# Rewrite all folder and files with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want all files and folder links change

I use below code for this problem, but not work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(\.zip|\.pdf|\.jpg|\.png)$ index.php?file=$1$2 [NC,L]
```

I want change actual url to another url automatic

`upload/1.png => index.php?file=/upload/1.png`

`upload/in/2.png => index.php?file=/upload/in/1.png`

Comment: What is not working? Provide details.

Comment: @anubhava I want if user open my directory, he see new url not actual url

Comment: `index.php` I edited my question. sorry

Comment: You need to change the URLs in your application. Don't redirect these requests in `.htaccess` (that's only for SEO purposes, if the URLs have already been indexed / linked to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?file=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+\.(?:zip|pdf|jpe?g|png)$ index.php?file=$0 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thank you, but not work me: please check this image and url of 1.png : http://tinyimg.io/i/T2rgjGX.png ( left bottom )

Comment: I need to be offline for few hours for some work. But you've misunderstood it. Directory listing must not be displayed in browser for security reasons Just have a web page with href links as `/1.jpg`, `/image.png` etc and this rule will forward it to `/index.php?file=1.jpg`